# get recent inserted Row by time in join query

Tags: mysql, sql, database

i have four tables.

1. bank

[image]

2. balance 
   [image]
3. company

[image]

4. relation

[image]

From below query i am geeting below result

```
SELECT A.bank_name,
        B.comp_name,
        C.b_num,
        C.balance_now 
FROM balance C 
LEFT JOIN relation D 
    ON C.relation_id=D.s_no 
LEFT JOIN bank A 
    ON A.bank_id=D.bank_id 
LEFT JOIN company B 
    ON B.comp_id=D.comp_id 
GROUP BY C.relation_id
```

OUTPUT

[image]

Expected Output : From balance table i want to get relation_id,balance using time field i.e., most recent time.

Comment: For next time, please provide formatted text instead of pictures

Comment: sure. next time i will...

Comment: Maybe this is next time ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You could concat date and time columns to get datetime column, order by it and using LIMIT select top 1 row, something like:

```
SELECT A.bank_name,
        B.comp_name,
        C.b_num,
        C.balance_now ,
        C.relation_id
FROM balance C 
LEFT JOIN relation D 
    ON C.relation_id=D.s_no 
LEFT JOIN bank A 
    ON A.bank_id=D.bank_id 
LEFT JOIN company B 
    ON B.comp_id=D.comp_id 
GROUP BY C.relation_id
ORDER BY concat(C.date,' ',C.time) DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: limit will give only one row. but i want to get each and every last relation_id from balance table using recent time